# Laravel 6.10 -> Route [admin.dashboard] not defined. But other routes are working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

This is my routes/web.php file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', 'Admin\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login.post');
    Route::get('logout', 'Admin\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('admin.dashboard.index');
        })->name('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

and my admin.dashboard named route is not working. I cant found on web the solution of the problem. Please help.

my login controller:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ], $request->get('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }
        return back()->withInput(\request()->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
```

Comment: In what way is the route not working? Is it throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have it prepended with something else. The easiest way to find out, is to run `php artisan route:list` and see the name. The command will return something like

```
| Domain | Method | URI    | Name            | Action | Middleware |
|        | GET    | /admin | admin.dashboard | GET    | auth.admin |
```